# is there any method to hide the message below "No result Found "

Tags: reactjs

- **i am using react type ahead npm package **
  **https://ericgio.github.io/react-bootstrap-typeahead/#asynchronous-searching**

  [image]

  i want to show only  matching result not any other message in
  dropdown like its showing no match found!

Answer (score 0):

Does using

```js
emptyLabel=''
```

as a property work for you?

Eg:

```js
<AsyncTypeahead
  id="async-example"
  emptyLabel=''
```

If you want to the entire bottom menu option to disappear, I'd recommend submitting a patch to the project:

```
diff --git a/src/components/Menu.react.js b/src/components/Menu.react.js
index 9e403f9..c25b2f5 100644
--- a/src/components/Menu.react.js
+++ b/src/components/Menu.react.js
@@ -83,12 +83,12 @@ class Menu extends React.Component<MenuComponentProps> {
     } = this.props;

     const contents = Children.count(children) === 0 ?
-      <BaseMenuItem disabled role="option">
+      (emptyLabel ? <BaseMenuItem disabled role="option">
         {emptyLabel}
-      </BaseMenuItem> :
+      </BaseMenuItem> : null) :
       children;

-    return (
+    return contents ? (
       <ul
         aria-label={this.props['aria-label']}
         className={cx('rbt-menu', 'dropdown-menu', 'show', className)}
@@ -108,7 +108,7 @@ class Menu extends React.Component<MenuComponentProps> {
         }}>
         {contents}
       </ul>
-    );
+    ) : null;
   }
 }
```

Comment: i tried that  one but  after that  blank white bar showing without message!

Comment: by using this  can  i see the  result in dropdown? or every thing will be gone???

Comment: You'll see the result in the dropdown but you won't see the message that says that no results were found. Work with the author [here](https://github.com/ericgio/react-bootstrap-typeahead/issues) to submit the change.